# Is it good design to loop through many users? - SpringBoot

Tags: spring, performance, spring-boot, design-patterns

I am looking into good design principles and would just like some feedback.

I want to go through every user in my application that is a patient, check their scheduled activities, see if there is one upcoming and send them an email. It looks a little like this:

```
 List<Patient> listOfAllPatients = patientRepositoryJPA.findAll();

    if (listOfAllPatients.size() != 0) {

        for (Patient patient : listOfAllPatients) {

            user = userRepositoryJPA.findByUsername(patient.getUsername());

            Timestamp currentTimeAndDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Long closestDate = Integer.toUnsignedLong(31);;

            List<Activity> activities = activityRepositoryJPA.findByPatientAndStartDateTimeAfter(patient, currentTimeAndDate);

            for (Activity activity : activities) {

                Timestamp activityDateAndTime = activity.getStartDateTime();

                Long difference = getTimeDifferenceByMinutes(currentTimeAndDate, activityDateAndTime);

                if (difference < closestDate) {

                    LocalDateTime upcomingDate = activity.getStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime();

                    emailHandler.sendEmail(javaMailSender, "Upcoming Activity Reminder", "The activity, " + activity.getName() + " is starting soon! (" +
                            upcomingDate.getHour() + ":" + upcomingDate.getMinute() + ")", user);
                }

            }
        }
```

Now here I loop through every patient in the application and then through each of their activities. If there were many user (millions) surely there would be some bottlenecks or something here.

Does anybody have any advice on how big companies would handle data like this?

Or is what I am doing fine? Thanks.

> After some advice, I have improved it to this:

```
    Timestamp currentTimeAndDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    LocalDateTime add31Minutes = LocalDateTime.now().plus(31, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    Timestamp noLaterThanDateAndTime = Timestamp.valueOf(add31Minutes);

      for (Activity activity : activityRepositoryJPA.findByStartDateTimeBetween(currentTimeAndDate, noLaterThanDateAndTime)) {

        Patient patient = activity.getPatient();

        LocalDateTime upcomingDate = activity.getStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime();

        emailHandler.sendEmail(javaMailSender, "BAA - Upcoming Activity Reminder", "The activity, " + activity.getName() + " is starting soon! (" +
                upcomingDate.getHour() + ":" + upcomingDate.getMinute() + ")", patient.getUser());
    }
```

Now I find all activities between now and 31 minutes time in 1 query.

Comment: I share your concern of inefficiency.  If there are only a few patients with schedules, wouldn't it make more sense to pull out the schedules and just loop over those rather than looping over patients just to check schedules by patient?  Whether that's feasible probably depends on the API functions at your disposal to look up activities.

Comment: No, this is not good at all. You need to look at pagination, for example [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html). This allows you to _stream_ data out of the data source rather than `findAll` which will yank the whole lot into RAM - a Bad Idea TM.

Comment: You should be able to find the activities  between now and now + 31 minutes in a single query. And then loop through these activities and send an email for each of them. Let the database do the filtering for you. This should hopefully load way less entities in memory. If it's still a lot, then iterate through the result instead of loading the list in memory.

Comment: You also need to look into joining queries - you need to get all the patients and their activities in a single query and then iterate that, rather than excuting an additonal query for each patient.

Comment: Further, you recaclulate the timestamp every iteration - that's going to lead to odd results.

Comment: The activity method 'findByPatientAndStartDateTimeAfter' finds all activities in the next 31 minutes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I throught the PagingAndSortingRepository allowed you to get like the first 20 or whatever at a time. Are you suggesting maybe just incrementing this paging each time? As i need to go through them all.

Comment: That's most simplistic option I can think of - [`Page.nextPageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#nextPageable--). There are more complex options; but given you have asked this question I thought the simplest apporach would be the best start. You can then, as @JBNizet suggests, look into running the entire query in the database and iterating the results with a cursor - this would be the correct "enterprise" implementation.

Comment: *The activity method 'findByPatientAndStartDateTimeAfter' finds all activities in the next 31 minutes.*: no. It find all the activities after now, for 1 patient. Use a query that retrieves all activities, for all patients, starting betwen now and now + 31 minutes. Then iterate over the result. So no need to load all patients in memory, and no need to execute one query per patient, and no need to manually filter out activities starting later than now + 31 minutes. A single query, to retrieve exactly what you want, in one go.

Comment: @JBNizet ah okay. Yes that makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet Implemented your suggestion in question edit.

Comment: You haven't really - you still have a query per iteration and you are still loading the whole lot into memory.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I need a query per iteration in order to find the user linked to that activity so that I can send an email to the user. This is a problem with my database structure as a User entity is not related to a Patient entity. So I have to query to find the user from the patient username.

Comment: Learn about joins and queries in JPA criteria queries and their integrations with Spring. The current solution is still very naive. Running a query is not free, and running queries in loops is (almost) always a mistake as a databaise is much better at looping than you are.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Changed the database structure. Using JPA join a Patient is now linked to a user.

Comment: Check the queries on the database to ensure that it's not running another query for `activity.getPatient()`. You may need to define a [JPA named entity graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm). Otherwise, looks much better.

Comment: Or a simple `left join fetch` clause.